# build absolute value equations know solution

Tags: equation-solving, algebraic-manipulation

We have absolute value equations with unknown coefficients:

```
|x + a| = b
```

and we know solutions:

```
x = 11 and x = 5
```

We need to find a and b.

```
11 + a = b
5 + a = -b
```

We get a = 8 and b = 3

But we can try other way:

```
11 + a = -b
5 + a = b
```

and get a =8 and b = -3, which is not correct, apparently we need take absolute value from b.

How to formulate this rule and explain it to other person?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach is to solve the equations directly with

```
Solve[{Abs[11 + a] == b, Abs[5 + a] == b}]
(* {{a -> -8, b -> 3}} *)
```

Note that,

```
Solve[{11 + a == b, 5 + a == -b}]
(* {{a -> -8, b -> 3}} *)
```

not "a = 8 and b = 3" as in the question, and

```
Solve[{11 + a == -b, 5 + a == b}]
{* {{a -> -8, b -> -3}} *)
```

not "a =8 and b = -3" as in the question.  In any case `{a -> -8, b -> -3}` is inconsistent with replacing `Abs[5 + a] == b` by `5 + a == b`, which is why the final calculation is wrong.

Comment: @Alex  The first line of code in my answer solves for `a` and `b` without having to remove the `Abs[]`, which can be error-prone.  See my further discussion, which I just added.  I hope this helps.

Comment: I just understand that I asked on the wrong site, this site is for Wolfram Mathematica, and this answer is perfectly valid for this site, probably I should ask in Mathematics.